# Android- Loading Contacts with ViewHolder and AsyncTask- Thumbnail issue

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-asynctask, thumbnails, android-contacts

I am creating a custom contact app.. I use a ArrayAdapter with ViewHolder design pattern for optimization...Since it took a lot of time to load the thumbnail pics, I use AsyncTask class for loading images, for the first set of contacts in my screen, the pics are loading well but when I scroll down, the same set of pictures are being re-cycled at random for other contacts...I have searched this forumn and found a few solutions but none worked for me. I shall put my code below.. Someone pls tell me what is wrong in the code instead of marking it as duplicate qn...

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<String> displayName,demoteValue,emergency;
    ArrayList<Long> contactId;

    public CustomList(Activity context,ArrayList<Long> contactId,ArrayList<String> displayName,ArrayList<String> demoteValue ,
            ArrayList<String> emergency) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, displayName);
        this.context = context;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.demoteValue = demoteValue;
        this.emergency = emergency;
        this.contactId=contactId;

    }

    class MyViewHolder
    {
        public QuickContactBadge imageView;
        public TextView txtTitle;
        int position;

        MyViewHolder(View v){
            txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            imageView = (QuickContactBadge) v.findViewById(R.id.contactimageentry);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView=convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder=null;

        if(rowView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);
             holder=new MyViewHolder(rowView);
             rowView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder= (MyViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(displayName.get(position));
        holder.txtTitle.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Some BLA BLA BLA work.
        if(emergency.get(position).equals("1")){

            holder.txtTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,25);
            holder.imageView.getLayoutParams().width=getPixels(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,50);

}            
        //Get and set the photo-HERE LIES THE CALL TO THE PROBLEM
        holder.position = position;
        new LoadContactImage(getContext(),holder,position,contactId.get(position))
        .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);       
        return rowView;
    }   
}
```

And here is the code for my Async Task that loads the images based on the ID which I have passed while calling it

```
public class LoadContactImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

private long Path;
private MyViewHolder mHolder;
private int mposition;
Context ctx;

public LoadContactImage(Context context,MyViewHolder holder,int position,Long id) {
    this.mHolder= holder;
    this.Path = id;
    this.mposition=position;
    this.ctx= context;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
    Uri my_uri = getPhotoUri(Path);
    ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = cr.openInputStream(my_uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (result != null && mposition == mHolder.position) {
        //imv.setImageBitmap(result);
        mHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: i don't see a problem here. You should probably call  holder.imageView.setImageBitmap to whatever it was originally when you first create your holder in your getView Method. Otherwise the image still has the old value until the loading finishes.

Comment: Thanks or ur response...But I dont really get your change..Can u pls illustarte it or highlight the code that should be changed?

Comment: in the line before you start your loading AsyncTask you should set the holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(loadingImage) since otherwise the old image is still shown, Since the ListView recycles its views - the one that scrolls out at the top is reinserted at the bottom (and other way).

Comment: So do u mean that I have to return the result found in onPostExecute(Bitmap result) back to getView() and set the image there by using holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(returnedImage); ??

Comment: no - you just have to set the image back to some initial state in the get view method, before starting the background loading

Comment: holder.imageView.setImageURI( Uri.parse("android.resource://com.vishnu.demotingprototype/drawable/ic_contact_picture"));                                              I had tried adding this line before calling the AsyncTask..Now most of the COntact ppics that had apppered b4 are not appearing...and the accuracy rate has improved to 80% and not 100%...Any reason why? still the problem s not completly solved

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41799/discussion-between-bala-vishnu-and-simon-meyer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out...Now its working..Soln given by Simon Meyer in Comments is correct..I need to initialize the imageView to a bitmap in getView() before I could call Async Task..Here is the change in code

```
holder.position = position;

holder.imageView.setImageURI( Uri.parse("android.resource://com.vishnu.demotingprototype/drawable/ic_contact_picture"));

new LoadContactImage(getContext(),holder,position,contactId.get(position)).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your customclass is not find out the context of lader image class.
Declare context in yorr activity first.all is going well rather than this....Its works fine

Comment: But sir both these class are not inside my activity..I have put them as seperate classes...so getContext() is not working, tats why I had passed context as an argument to the Async class...do u mean it's the problem? if so how to get the Context?