# bad update image in listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

i use this code for a custum listview

**Custom ListView**

```
public class ListAdapt extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public ListAdapt(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // title
    TextView title1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name1);
    TextView title2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.idi);


    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(online.KEY_NAME));
    title2.setText(song.get(online.KEY_ID));
    title1.setText(song.get(online.KEY_DESC));
    String as = title1.getText().toString();

    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
    .execute(as);



    return vi;
}
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
      ImageView bmImage;

      public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
          this.bmImage = bmImage;
      }

      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String urldisplay = urls[0];
          Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
          try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return mIcon11;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
          bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
    }
}
```

in custom listview use a Asynctask , load image from URL in Asynctask .

URL = String is

this code work and load image but when touch scroll in phone , Cluttered listview image .

**ListActivity**

```
public class online extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://titanz13.byethost10.com/codee.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

           setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
           getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.online);



        new GetContacts().execute();





        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById

                        (R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String h = ((TextView) view.findViewById

                        (R.id.idi)).getText().toString();
                 int mynum = Integer.parseInt(h);

                 if (mynum==1){

                     Uri uri = Uri.parse(name); 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
                        startActivity(intent);

                 }else {



                Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
                whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, name);
                try {
                    startActivity(whatsappIntent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "نرم افزار واتس اپ بر روی دستگاه شما نصب نیست";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }   
                 }

            }
        });
    }









    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(online.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {



            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
            }
            // Adding menuItems to ListView


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapt adapter = new ListAdapt(online.this, menuItems);

            setListAdapter(adapter);



        }

    }
```

Comment: Eli, I think you have to use Android Query to download the images, its working perfect in all the cases,

Comment: Try putting a log statement in your getView() method. See how often you are calling your image download? Even for the same rows. You should investigate downloading images for a List Adapter. There are many tutorials searchable by [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lazy%20loading%20images%20for%20list%20adapter). You should also investigate the ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: Resolved. Thank you to the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173132/android-loading-contacts-with-viewholder-and-asynctask-thumbnail-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cluttered because you are following a bad practice to load remote URLs/Images into ImageView inside ListView.

You need to follow the best practices to load Image into ImageView inside ListView. One best practice is to implement **lazy loading of images** logic. Using which images would be loaded in background and cached into the memory so that it would load images from cache rather than downloading it again.

There are many libraries available on the web with the same implementation, I have written a post on some of the libraries: [Image loading library](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-5-image-loading-library/)

(P.S. Sorry for placing a link inside answer as I can't include required parts from the original link because it's lengthy and Sorry for including a personal blog link but it's required here for the reference.)

Comment: I can definitely recommend Picasso for this particular instance